# Load flexslider after load more post with ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I tried many methods, but it did not work out to download the flex slider in the modal window after clicking on the load more button.

I understand I need to make a second request to call the script, but I don't understand how to do it, my knowledge is clearly not enough

A very big request to help, is clearly my knowledge not enough :(

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="postModal<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="max-width:70%">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="float:right;border:none;"></button>
            <div class="row-popup">
            <div class="col-popup-left">
                <?php $images = get_field('gallery');
                    if( $images ): ?>
            <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
                            <ul class="slides">
                    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                            <li><img src="<?php echo esc_url($image['url']); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" /></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
            </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
        <div class="col-popup-right">
                  <h5 class="portfolio-title"><?php the_field('game-type')?></h5>
          <p class="portfolio-customer"><?php the_field('customer')?></p>
          <p class="portfolio-review"><?php the_field('review')?></p>
          <p class="portfolio-price"><?php the_field('quantity')?></p>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->

<?php if($args['layout'] == "1"){ ?>
<div class="am_grid_col" >
<div data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#postModal<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="am_single_grid"><div class="more-button"><p>show more</p></div>
<div class="am_thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?></div>
<div class="am_cont">
    <h2 class="am__title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2></a>
    <div class="portfolio-price--grid"><?php the_field('quantity-and-price'); ?></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } else if( $args['layout'] == 2 ){ ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>

script

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".am-post-grid-load-more").click(function () {
            var eventname = $(this).attr('id');
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                action: "all_event",
                eventname: eventname
                },
                  success: function (response) {
                    $(".am_grid_col").html(response);
                    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                      animation: "slide",
                      slideshow: "false",
                      animationLoop: true,
                      itemWidth: 192,
                      itemMargin: 9,
                      controlNav: true,
                      directionNav: false
                    });
                  }
              });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well what you need exactly, You can add a `callback` function to the success parameter of the `AJAX` request that initializes `FlexSlider` for each new post, So you can modify you code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".am-post-grid-load-more").click(function () {
        var eventname = $(this).attr('id');
        var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: "all_event",
                eventname: eventname
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var $newPosts = $(response).find('.am_grid_col');

                // Replace existing posts with new posts
                $('.am_grid_col').append($newPosts);

                // Initialize FlexSlider for each new post
                $newPosts.find('.flexslider').each(function () {
                    $(this).flexslider({
                        animation: "slide",
                        slideshow: "false",
                        animationLoop: true,
                        itemWidth: 192,
                        itemMargin: 9,
                        controlNav: true,
                        directionNav: false
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but nothing happens and a eror in the console `POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400`